# JBoss EAP 7.2 Oracle Hibernate Dialect

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jboss, dialect

I am using JBoss EAP 7.2 with Oracle 12c ojdbc7.jar
The application used to work. However after a restart of the JBoss Server I now get

```
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"monitoring4.war#primary\"" => "org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [oorg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oorg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oorg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"}}
```

I have used a simple persistence.xml without a hibernate dialect

```
<persistence version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="primary">
  
  
     <jta-data-source>java:/blabla</jta-data-source> 

  <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
    
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> 
    
   
  </properties>
```

I have tried to add

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" 
              value="oorg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>
```

no I get

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"monitoring4.war#primary\"" => "org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [oorg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oorg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oorg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"}}
```

What Oracle dialect should I use with EAP 7.2 ???
Any idea why the application has stopped working without any change (that I know of) certainly not in the project.

Thanks,

Hans

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" 
              value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of **hibernate-core** is in your project/JBoss instance(depends if your war or JBoss provides it).

`org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` is supported from hibernate-core >= 5.0.